# ¿Por qué el plural de "álbum" es irregular?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, plurales, latín

Hoy he visto en la tele escrita la palabra *ultimátums* y me he acordado del plural de *álbum*: *álbumes*. Buscando la explicación de esto [me encuentro](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1h):

> h) ***Sustantivos y adjetivos terminados en consonantes distintas de* -l, -r, -n, -d, -z, -j, -s, -x, -ch.** Se trate de onomatopeyas o de voces procedentes de otras lenguas, hacen el plural en *-s*: *crac*, pl. *cracs*; *zigzag*, pl. *zigzags*; *esnob*, pl. *esnobs*; *chip*, pl. *chips*; *mamut*, pl. *mamuts*; *cómic*, pl. *cómics*. Se exceptúa de esta regla la palabra *club*, que admite dos plurales, *clubs* y *clubes*. También son excepciones el arabismo *imam*, cuyo plural asentado es *imames*, y el latinismo *álbum*, cuyo plural asentado es *álbumes*.

Profundizando [un poco más](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1k):

> ***Plural de los latinismos.*** Aunque tradicionalmente se venía recomendando mantener invariables en plural ciertos latinismos terminados en consonante, muchos de ellos se han acomodado ya, en el uso mayoritario, a las reglas de formación del plural que rigen para el resto de las palabras y que han sido expuestas en los párrafos anteriores. Así pues, y como norma general, los latinismos hacen el plural en *-s*, en *-es* o quedan invariables dependiendo de sus características formales, al igual que ocurre con el resto de los préstamos de otras lenguas: *ratio*, pl. *ratios*; *plus*, pl. *pluses*; *lapsus*, pl. *lapsus*; *nomenclátor*, pl. *nomenclátores*; *déficit*, pl. *déficits*; *hábitat*, pl. *hábitats*; *vademécum*, pl. *vademécums*; *ítem*, pl. *ítems*. Únicamente se apartan hoy de esta tendencia mayoritaria los latinismos terminados en *-r* procedentes de formas verbales, como *cónfer*, *confíteor*, *exequátur* e *imprimátur*, cuyo plural sigue siendo invariable. También constituye una excepción la palabra *álbum*.

Es decir, procedentes del latín tenemos *ultimátums*, *vademécums*, *ítems* y en cambio *álbumes*. El [Ngram confirma](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A1lbumes%2C%C3%A1lbums&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%C3%A1lbumes%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A1lbumes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%81lbumes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A1lbums%3B%2Cc0) este asentamiento del plural:

[image: Álbumes]

Sin embargo, se ve en la gráfica que hacia 1880 la forma *álbums* parecía prevalecer. Ejemplo:

> *Un descendiente del autor que ha hecho muchas biografías, álbums y coronas poéticas a su memoria, negó la autenticidad de estas cartas, pero sin convencer a nadie.*
>
> Marcelino Menéndez Pelayo, ["Historia de los heterodoxos españoles"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IjHNwB4tOS0C&pg=PA612&lpg=PA612&dq="Un+descendiente+del+autor+que+ha+hecho+muchas+biograf%C3%ADas,+%C3%A1lbums+y+coronas+po%C3%A9ticas+a+su+memoria,+neg%C3%B3+la+autenticidad+de+estas+cartas,+pero+sin+convencer+a+nadie."), 1880-1881 (España).

Si fue así, y de hecho el caso más antiguo de *álbums* en el CORDE es unos 30 años anterior al primero de *álbumes*, ¿por qué acabó prevalenciendo la forma irregular *álbumes*? ¿Fue algo debido a la etimología de la palabra, o a recomendaciones de la propia RAE por aquel tiempo? ¿O simplemente era más fácil de pronunciar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que es una consecuencia de su pronunciación.

Los préstamos a castellano que terminan in "-m" generalmente se pronuncian "-n",<sup>1</sup> así que [*álbum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A1lbum#Spanish) se pronuncia vulgarmente `/ˈalbun/` y siguiendo las reglas normales de palabras castellanas, las que terminan en "-n" se pluralizan "-es". Eso también explicaría la otra excepción que notas *imames* (de hecho hay las formas castellanizadas *imán/imanes*),<sup>2</sup> y aquellas en un período de 'transición' teniendo dos formas aceptadas e.j. [*items/ítemes*](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/album-albumes-albums/) etc.

Las otras palabras o son muy cultas (e.j. préstamos crudos del latín) o muy poco comunes, y por eso supongo que no se han desarrollado formas naturalizadas.

Nota que la RAE no es consistente en su consejo, y por ejemplo también pluraliza los endonimios *[mam](https://dle.rae.es/?id=O5V76vC)/mames, [pocomam](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TTVQzzi)/pocomames* de la manera no prescriptiva.

---

<sup>1. e.j. inglés *rum* > [*ron*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WfgeA84); CD-ROM > [[se-de-rrón, ze-de-rrón]](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sigla) (sino *film* > [*filme*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HvPT03q))</sup>
<sup>2. Nota los dobletes *harem/harén, CD-ROM/[cederrón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=862rrly), [plim](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TPvF6Y5)/plin, [cataplum](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7uaObpx)/cataplún, [macadam](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NkgYDnm)/macadán, [pum](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UeBDBDa)/pun, [rum rum](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Wq2E0Dg)/runrún, [tamtam](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Z3el204)/tamtán, tantán*</sup>