# ¿Cómo se pluraliza "currículum"?

Tags: plurales, abreviaturas, latinismo

El DPD solo nota la forma plural de la locución "[currículum vítae](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=curr%C3%ADculum)" (que es invariable), pero no la propia palabra [currículum](https://dle.rae.es/?w=curr%C3%ADculum).

¿Cómo se pluraliza?

- Currículums (como *ítem → ítems*)?
- Curricúlumes (como *régimen → regímenes*)?
- Curriculumes (como *carácter → caracteres*)?

---

<sup>Muy relacionado:</sup>
<sup>• [¿Por qué el plural de régimen es "regímenes" y no "régimenes"? Y lo mismo con espécimen y carácter](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18445/por-qu%C3%A9-el-plural-de-r%C3%A9gimen-es-reg%C3%ADmenes-y-no-r%C3%A9gimenes-y-lo-mismo-con-es)</sup>
<sup>• [¿Por qué el plural de "álbum" es irregular?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/por-qu%c3%a9-el-plural-de-%c3%a1lbum-es-irregular)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La RAE recomienda ***currículums***:

> [#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/hashtag/RAEconsultas?src=hashtag_click) El plural del latinismo adaptado «currículum» es «currículums».
> <sub>[@RAEinforma 8:36 AM · Feb 12, 2013](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/301248457732132864)</sub>

Aunqué solía aconsejar que ciertos latinismos simples terminados en consonante queden invariables, en el uso popular se han adoptado como cualquier otro sustantivo (ej. *los ítem* → [*los ítems*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=los+%C3%ADtem%2Clos+%C3%ADtems&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3)) y ya los consejos de la RAE se alinean con esto.<sup>2 3 4</sup>

Nótese que en algunas sociolectas la forma 'culta' *currícula* se emplea, por influencia del [inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Irregular_plurals_from_Latin_and_Greek) (que suele intentar adoptar los sufijos originales con préstamos del latín o griego). La RAE postuló este sufijo en los años sesenta,<sup>5</sup> pero vacilaba y en los años noventa ya se lo consideraba *currícula* 'francamente rebuscado'.<sup>6</sup> Hoy en día renega de tal consejo:

> No deben usarse en español los plurales latinos en *-a* propios de los sustantivos neutros, tales como **córpora, *currícula*, etc., que sí son normales en otras lenguas como el inglés.
>
> - [DPD: Plural 1. k) *Plural de los latinismos*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1k)

---

**Notas**

<sup>1. [*Minucias del lenguaje*](https://www.fondodeculturaeconomica.com/obra/suma/r2/buscar.asp?idPALABRA=308&starts=Todos&word=curr%EF%BF%BDcula,%20memoranda,%20c%EF%BF%BDrpora,%20campi...) (currícula...; currículum...)</sup>
<sup>2. [DPD: Plural](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1k) (1.k)</sup>
<sup>3. [*Nueva gramática de la lengua española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nf7jCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT211&dq=3.3f) (3.3f, g, h)</sup>
<sup>4. [*Manual de la Nueva Gramática de la lengua española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kUekCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&dq=%22plural+de+los+latinismos%22) (3.2.4a)</sup>
<sup>5. [*Esbozo de una Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Esbozo_de_una_nueva_gram%C3%A1tica_de_la_len.html?id=FMZiAAAAMAAJ) (2.3.2c), 1973</sup>
<sup>6. [*Gramática descriptiva de la lengua española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RI1dAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA4463&dq=curr%C3%ADculum) (68.1.2.3; 68.1.3.2; 68.4.2.2; 74.3.3.5), 2009</sup>

Answer (score -1):

La pluralización de *currículum* está definida por la de *currículum vítae* y por lo tanto dada por la RAE. Explico:

Del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas en [*currículum vítae*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=curr%C3%ADculum):

> Esta locución es invariable en plural: *los currículum vítae*.

Aquí, *vítae* (sin tilde) es *vida* en genitivo, en latín. La información de la RAE es sobre *currículum vítae*, pero ésta determina la forma del plural de *currículum* de la siguiente forma: El substantivo principal es *currículum* y éste recibe una inflexión si y sólo si *currículum vítae* la recibe.

**Ejemplo:** ¿Cuál es el plural de *régimen de gobierno*? El plural es *regímenes de gobierno* (no *regímenes de gobiernos* u otra forma). Un **hecho** es que el plural sólo afecta el nombre principal, que es aquí *régimen.

En el caso de **currículum vítae** el análisis es

> **currículum    /     vítae**
>      *nombre raíz* / *complemento en genitivo* ("de vida")

Esto implica que *currículum* es invariable.  Aceptar otra forma de plural es equivalente a aceptar que *régimen de gobierno* tenga un plural como *regímenes de gobierno* pero *régimen* tenga una forma plural diferente (digamos *régimens*). Esto no pasa en ningún lenguaje.